# SQL Pull Top 1 of many Unique IDs and Combine

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Hi I'm trying to combine 2 SQL tables using SQL query in SSMS. The first just directly pulling 4 columns from a table with 1 entry per ID#. The second is a historical change table where I need the first time an item changed to a specific state for all unique ID#'s.
Thank you to any and all respondents.

*What I have:*

`CurrentView`

```
ID      Create      Resolve   Effort
1234    1/10/2017   1/10/2017   5
1235    1/11/2017   1/11/2017   8
1236    1/12/2017   1/12/2017   25
1278    1/13/2017   1/13/2017   34
1347    1/14/2017   1/14/2017   76
```

`HistoryView`

```
ID      Status  Timestamp
1234    prep      12:01
1234    working   13:01
1234    working   14:01
1235    prep      3:05
1235    working   4:05
1235    working   5:05
```

*What I need:*

```
ID      Create      Resolve     Effort  First time set to Working
1234    1/10/2017   1/10/2017   5       13:01
1235    1/11/2017   1/11/2017   8       4:05
1236    1/12/2017   1/12/2017   25      8:07
1278    1/13/2017   1/13/2017   34      11:45
1347    1/14/2017   1/14/2017   76      5:45
```

Comment: Can you please describe your question further? How do you want to combine these?

Comment: Removed the DBMS specific tags. Please add back the DBMS you are actually using.

Comment: ssms tag added @Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very straightforward way of doing this would be:

```
SELECT 
  c.*, 
  (SELECT MIN([timestamp]) FROM HistoryView h 
   WHERE h.id = c.id and h.status = 'working') as "First time"
FROM
  CurrentView
WHERE ...
```

PS. Not tested. You may have trouble with the column named "timestamp", as it's a reserved word.

Comment: Awesome. This worked Mustaccio! Thanks! I up arrowed the answer but it says since I'm a noob it won't show. Anything else to be done when someone answers a Q?

Comment: Hi Dave, my guess is that he answered very quickly and there's a 15-minute grace period so other people can answer, too. Check it again and you should be able to choose mustaccio's answer. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Ah. It lets me Green Check but I cant up vote for lack of reputation. Thanks for the link @Russell